# C fscanf read character or integer

Tags: c

I need to read characters and integers from a text file using fscanf, but I don't know whether the next value is going to be a character or an integer. How do I do something like

```
if(next_is_character)
    fscanf(file, "%c", &mycharacter);
else
    fscanf(file, "%d", &myinteger);
```

Comment: Why are you using & in fprintf() ?

Comment: question is not clear with the given code

Comment: You can read as a string, and then check if it's a single character or a number. Or read a single character, if it's a digit, read the rest as a number.

Comment: `but I don't know whether the next value is going to be a character or an integer` Then you're using the wrong tool, since `fscanf` reads a _known_ format.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%c",&charvar))
{
    if(isalpha(charvar))
     {
        //it is character
      }
     if(isdigit(charvar))
     {
        //it is integer
      }
}
```

you can use this functions

```
#include <ctype.h>

int isalnum(int c);
int isalpha(int c);
int isascii(int c);
int isblank(int c);
int iscntrl(int c);
int isdigit(int c);
int isgraph(int c);
int islower(int c);
int isprint(int c);
int ispunct(int c);
int isspace(int c);
int isupper(int c);
int isxdigit(int c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read everything as c-string and validate by using **[strtol](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtol.3.html)**.

If `strtol` fails to convert the string into integer then it's character. Otherwise, it's an integer.

```
char *endptr;

fscanf(fp, "%s", str);

myInteger = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);

// Check the errno for errors
```

Comment: I consider this messy, because an error condition is raised on normal operation, but in this case, might be acceptable. I would use `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been messing around and I found something like this could work:

```
fpos_t position;
fgetpos (fp, &position);

char isCharacter;
fscanf(fp, "%c", &isCharacter);
if(isalpha(isCharacter))
{
        //it is character
}
else
{
    fsetpos(fp, &position);
    // integer, read it
}
```